# How to translate legacy (OLE) colors to (A)RGB with .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, ole, colortransform

I have a list of color values encoded as signed integers (OLE I think) in a legacy INI file that I need to translate into (A)RGB values with .NET. An INI example:

> ```
> [INI_Section]
> Color=-2147483633
> ```

Doing something like:

```
Color.FromArgb(-2147483633)
```

gives an alpha-blended version of a color that is not at all what I expect. I think that a value like -2147483633 is supposed to represent a system-defined, or named color like ButtonFace. Is there a .NET method for translating these legacy colors properly? Note that pInvoke to OlePro32.dll is not an option.

Comment: Your number comes out as `FFFFFFFF8000000F` in hex (on the Windows calculator) - do you know what colour the number (or indeed any number you have) is supposed to represent?

Comment: @ChrisF: Use DWord, not QWord... the value is `8000000F` which, in ARGB, would be a partially transparent white, with just a hint of blue.  Perhaps it is actually an ARGB-1/10/11/10, or RGBA (both of which would be pink)

Comment: @BlueRaja - I've just realised that, but it's too late to edit my comment :(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use ColorTranslator.FromOle to do the conversion. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.colortranslator.fromole.aspx

Comment: +1. A bit more from the docs. "If an OLE_COLOR has its high-order bit set, the low-order byte is treated as a system color index" http://support.microsoft.com/kb/131101 So `8000000F` is indeed *button face* because the system colour COLOR_BTNFACE is at index 15 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724371(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

If from some reason you cannot use System.Drawing lib (e.g. in Azure function) than you can calculate like this:

```
                var ole = 6579300;
                var red = ole % 256;
                var green = (ole / 256) % 256;
                var blue = (ole / 65536) % 256;
                var backToOle = red + (green * 256) + (blue * 256 * 256);
```